# Does bulk editing questions in a survey form give better UX?

Tags: surveys, question-answer, edit

I am asked to give the option for bulk editing for a survey form. The user should be able to edit similar questions (like All Rating questions) at the same time, then bulk edit 1 question and "Apply All," so it gets applied to all questions of the same type, instead of having to edit each question individually.

Now my concern is, does bulk editing apply to all types of questions (multichoice, dropdown etc), as each question is unique, their responses are unique in the survey, how can I allow the "Apply All" option? Doesn't it duplicate questions in survey?

So what is the best practice? Only allow to edit questions individually or allow similar selected question types to be bulk edited?

Comment: Show us a visual example

Answer (score 1):

I guess that it all depends on the questions.

Bulk answering questions sounds like it can have negative consequences, e.g. humans can be lazy and now you are allowing them to be very lazy and not even think about the other questions.